# How to obtain an Italian dictionary to spell-check within GNU Emacs which correctly recognize accented characters?

Tags: software-installation, emacs, language-support, dictionary, spell-checking

I am editing documents in Italian with GNU Emacs and I am used to spell-check my files with `ispell`. I have an Italian dictionary already installed (the `iitalian` package for `ispell`), but it doesn't recognize accented characters, such as "í". For Spanish and Catalan I have `castellano8` and `catala8` options which recognize accented characters,  and also French dictionary works fine. Could anyone tell me how to obtain such an Italian dictionary for ispell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, the solution I found is to tell Emacs to use `aspell` instead of `ispell`. This is an spellchecker that works in the same way as `ispell`. This can be accomplished by adding this line in the `.emacs` file:

> ```
> (setq-default ispell-program-name "aspell")
> ```

To install the Italian dictionary I executed

> ```
> sudo apt-get install aspell-it
> ```

and similarly for dictionaries for other languages. All these dictionaries recognize correctly accented characters and work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The [iitalian file list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/iitalian/filelist) may give you a hint.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had a look at all these files, but it didn't help. I can't figure out why my ispell dictionaries recognize accented characters in Spanish, French and Catalan, but not in Italian.

Comment: @Charo: Ok.. Originally you asked how to **install** a dictionary, which gave me the impression that you already had a better Italian one.